# Discord.js How can i access a info in channel.members?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

```
var category = client.guilds.get('269811924399685634').channels.get('691715649625653450');
var channels = category.children.filter(c => c.type == 'voice');
var channel = channels.map(e => e);

for(var i=0;i<channel.length;i++)
{                         
      var member_info = channel[i].members;

}
```

I'm tried this. I'm received a long untyped text like json. But when i'm convert to string it will sent this string : '{}'. So i can't access any information in this untyped text. How can i access ? Can you help me?

Comment: What is the structure and format of data in `channel` variable here?

Comment: `channel` variable is a array of voice channels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to map a voiceChannels, then you can `map` members in this voiceChannel.

```js
var category = client.guilds.get('269811924399685634').channels.get('691715649625653450');
var channels = category.children.filter(c => c.type == 'voice').forEach(vcChannel => vcChannel.members.map(member => console.log(`$the member ${member.id} in voice ${vcChannel.name}`)));
```

Comment: Yes, this is right. but how can i delete channel which haven't user?

Comment: `var channels = category.children.filter(c => c.type == 'voice').forEach(vcChannel => vcChannel.members.map(member => member.id == undefined ? vcChannel.delete() : null  )); ` I'm tried this. But it didn't run.